# How can I override the method of view in Controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I made a custom View Cell that want to reuse. I want to add action to button in customView, that show side menu. So I wrote a code ReusableCustomView.swift like below.

```swift
class ResuableCustomView: UIView {
    let nibName = "ReusableCustomView"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryMenuBTn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIStackView!
    func showMenu(){
        print("tapped")
    }
    @IBAction func menuBtnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.showMenu()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
            print("Tappedd")
        }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            commonInit()
        }
        
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        view.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(view)
    }
    
    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    }

}
```

showing SideMenu Code is like below.

```swift
    func showSlideMenu(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let sideMenuViewController: SideMenuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuViewController") as! SideMenuViewController
        let menu = CustomSideMenuNavigation(rootViewController: sideMenuViewController)
        present(menu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

- The customized view is added to the storyboard and the ui is coming out well, and I want to override showMenu function so that i can show the side menu.
  How Can I Override that function by code? I'd appreciate it if you could let me know.
- ViewController code is below:

```swift
class categoryToViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var customViewCell: ResuableCustomView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 }

}
```

[storyBoard image that adopts ResuableCustomView Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEW2W.png)

[ReusableCell.xib image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqBxH.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first you better inherit from UIControll instead of UIView.
Because you can get the event.

1- change define a class to this line:

```
class ResuableCustomView: UIControl { ... }
```

2- add to UIView to custom UIViewController and sed Custom class to ResuableCustomView:

[image]

3- create function in ViewController for get Event:

```
@IBAction private func customViewTapped(_ sender: ResuableCustomView) {
        print("hello my friend :-)")
    }
```

4- inside ResuableCustomView class set Action by append this line to your function:

```
self.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
```

this line send event for use.
Here I used type touchUpInside.

change your showMenu function to below code:

```
func showMenu(){
        // set here callBack
        self.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside) // and create event function with touchUpInside type
        print("tapped")
    }
```

5- now back to storyboard and connect IBAction to callBack like This Picture:
[image]

6. run and click on button and see print like this:
   [image]

all code for CustomView:

```
// inheritance from UIControl instead of UIView
class ResuableCustomView: UIControl {
    let nibName = "ReusableCustomView"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryMenuBTn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIStackView!
    
    func showMenu(){
        // set here callBack
        self.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside) // and create event function with touchUpInside type
        print("tapped")
    }
    
    @IBAction func menuBtnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.showMenu()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
            print("Tappedd")
        }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            commonInit()
        }
        
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        view.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    }

}
```

all code for ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var customViewCell: ResuableCustomView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction private func customViewTapped(_ sender: ResuableCustomView) {
        print("hello my friend :-)")
    }
}
```

Comment: It works!!! Thank you very much. I'll keep looking at the code you told me and learn it. I hope you have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can directly add the button action menuBtnClicked inside the categoryToViewController since the ReusableCustomView is placed inside this ViewController.

```
class categoryToViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var customViewCell: ResuableCustomView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func menuBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        print("pressed")
    }

}
```

Comment: i tried but i can't make action directly to menuButton. I attached the picture that I tried to connect to under this article.

Comment: @lisa Please have a look into the gif added. Just click on the empty circle beside the IBAction and link it to the button.

Comment: Thank you so much for attaching the gif video. 
The part you mentioned is understood by inheriting the cell and creating a button on it and connecting it. 
The way I'm going to try is to show the side menu in the view controller when clicks the button declared in CustomViewCell. I want to use CustomViewCell serveral times, and use that button shows side menu to multiple views. I added gif file that shows my storyboard. Thanks for replying

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you for your help with the answer.